# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found

Tags: dll

Python python-3.9.13-amd64 works well in my windows 10 pro.
after uninstalling 3.9.13 and deleting "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\ directory , I have installed python-3.10.9-amd64.
It logs out with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\ccdtest1.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev  # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.core.util.hashing import (  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\util\hashing.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.base import _registry as registry
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\base.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.errors import AbstractMethodError
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\errors\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.
```

Attempts made:

1. pip uinstalled pandas and installed again.
2. Using regedit, I added C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\ to path.
3. I copied libcrypto-1_1.dll,libssl-1_1.dll,libffi-7.dll from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs to my py program directory.

problem remains.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. There were some .pyd files in my py programs directory. I removed all .pyd, from my py programs directory.
I have installed python 3.11.1 and everything working well now.